# Google Maps Store Finder query not returning properly

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, google-maps

I must first let you know that while I am an experienced rails developer, I am quite rusty at PHP and raw SQL.  I am attempting to build a store finder app using [this tutorial](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch.html) and [this tutorial](http://developer.practicalecommerce.com/articles/2198-Develop-a-Store-Finder-with-the-Google-Maps-API-Part-1).  I am meeting

This is the code I am using for my query (with my own database column names)

```
$user_lat = $_GET["lat"];
$user_lng = $_GET["lng"];
$radius = $_GET["radius"];

$query = "SELECT 'Address','LocName','Latitude','Longitude', ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians($user_lat) ) * cos( radians( Latitude ) ) * cos( radians( Longitude ) - radians($user_lng) ) + sin( radians($user_lat) ) * sin( radians( Latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM Locations ORDER BY distance";
```

And I am returning the results with this (just as a test):

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
  die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
}

$num=mysql_numrows($result);

mysql_close();
?>
<table border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
<tr>
<th><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Name</font></th>
<th><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Distance</font></th>
<th><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Address</font></th>
</tr>

<?php
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$f1=mysql_result($result,$i,"LocName");
$f2=mysql_result($result,$i,"distance");
$f3=mysql_result($result,$i,"Address");
?>

<tr>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f1; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f2 ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f3; ?></font></td>
</tr>

<?php
$i++;
}
?>
```

However I am getting the following results when i got go: findstore.php?lat=33.98&lng=-118.42

```
Name    Distance    Address
LocName     0.65415504532801    Address
LocName     0.65415504532801    Address
LocName     0.666819627384179   Address
LocName     0.923277344110443   Address
LocName     2.32751232712236    Address
LocName     2.33924574433009    Address
```

etc.

obviously the Distance is calculating properly but I am having trouble getting the Address and Location Name for each.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing the single quotes in your query with backticks.

i.e.:

```
$query = "SELECT `Address`,`LocName`,`Latitude`,`Longitude`, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians($user_lat) ) * cos( radians( Latitude ) ) * cos( radians( Longitude ) - radians($user_lng) ) + sin( radians($user_lat) ) * sin( radians( Latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM Locations ORDER BY distance";
```

Comment: When you wrap the column names in single quotes, it is selecting the literal string that you put in. `SELECT 'Address' ...` returns 'Address'. The backticks aren't necessary in this case, you could just query the column name without anything(`SELECT Address ...`) and it would work as well. The backticks are just a good practice.